# How to to get the prices centered in the node:teaser with commerce price savings formatter?

Tags: views, commerce

I am pretty new to drupal and I have a problem with formatting the price in my drupal shop. I am using commerce sale price -module and commerce price savings formatter -module.

In the default view, the price shows ok, in the right position. But in the view (node:teaser) it shows the prices in the wrong position. I have tried everything to get the prices centered (modifying the css), but they are still on right side all the time. I would also like to remove the line above the price if its possible.

Here is the link to my shop: http://www.oladevelopment.fi/mifuko/content/home-shop

Ant ideas on how I can get the prices shown in the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your CSS:

```
table.commerce-price-savings-formatter-prices{
width: 100%;
}
```

Also, you can add:

```
.commerce-price-savings-formatter-price .price-amount{
display: block;
padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Prices looks much better with this.

If `width:100%` doesn't work try to use `width:100% !important;` because width is already defined in module's theme.

To remove line above price add this to your CSS:

```
table.commerce-price-savings-formatter-prices tbody{
border-top:0;
}
```

Also, if it doesn't work, use `border-top:0 !important;` instead `border-top:0;`

To minimize the space between prices add to CSS:

```
table.commerce-price-savings-formatter-prices-down{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50%;
}
```

Important part here is `width: 50%;`, change this percent to see which space you want to have, the more percent is the more space will be between prices. Again, use `!important` if doesn't work.

You can also add this to your CSS to make prices look better (to make it equal at the bottom edge):

```
table.commerce-price-savings-formatter-prices-down tr td{
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Don't forget to clear cache.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the help! Now I got them centered! But I would still like to know how I get that line above the price removed? And now there is a big space between the over-lined normal price and the sale price, how can I minimize that space?

Comment: I updated my answer, look there how to remove line. Be more specific about what you want to do with space, I don't see any other price, there is only one price.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked and I got the line removed! The prices that are on sale have the gap between the normal price and the sale price: http://www.oladevelopment.fi/mifuko/product-category/discount-items 
How can I minimize that gap?

Comment: I updated the answer...